# Is this video showing an Apple engineer discussing the new MacBook (2015) authentic?

Tags: technology, video

This seems to be a video going viral online and some people are claiming it is legitimate.

It depicts an Apple employee mocking Apple's new MacBook for not having any type-A USB ports (used for normal USB) and for having a weak CPU.

You can find it here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHZ8ek-6ccc

How can I identify the source of this clip and verify if it is authentic or not?

Comment: from the video description: `Original Source: Risitas y las paelleras: https://youtu.be/cDphUib5iG4`

Comment: It's a meme: http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/el-risitas-interview-parodies

Comment: Just a couple of years ago, Apple stopped producing a thing with an optical (CD) drive. Quite a while before that, no floppy disks.

Comment: Description of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kAleXmxbq4 explains it well too

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The video doesn't seem to be authentic.

The video is used as a parody worldwide, it is international and labeled as a "video meme".

The series of the meme is called : ["El Risitas" Interview Parodies](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/el-risitas-interview-parodies)

What the meme-creator does is the following:

- ignore the content of the video
- pick any subject prone to criticism
- create the fake subtitles (usually using a video editor like Premiere Pro)

The video has extremely funny laughs as you see, with the combination of fit subtitles you get one extraordinary satirical meme.

For example, we used it in my university to criticize our university's rules and regulations, you can see our video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Xq0YykJbVA&list=LLejLqIAjsAS0ELFOrncyZOQ&index=31):
[image]

Another viral video was: [Pancho Aréna stadionavató](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6Q5FXvp6pw), criticising football results.

I have to reference this [hungarian article](http://444.hu/2013/10/14/ki-francesco-zombori-es-miert-nyerit/) which helped me figure out the name of the person found in the video meme.

I'm mentioning the [movies.stackexchange.com](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/32054/help-me-identify-the-source-of-this) community for helping me find the original video.

It turns out the guy's name is [Juan Joya Borja](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Risitas), who is an Actor and a comedian Spanish known for appearing in the programs of Jesus Quintero and in films like Torrente 3: El protector.

He's commonly known as "Risitas" or "El Risitas", literally meaning "little laughs" or "giggles", due to the way he laughs during his jokes and stories. He became very known in Spain.

You can see the original video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDiB4rtp1qw) with English subtitles [where](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/el-risitas-interview-parodies) he:

> was interviewed by host Jesus Quintero on the Spanish-language
>   television program Ratones Coloraos, and he burst into laughter
>   after telling a humorous anecdote about throwing kitchen pans into the
>   sea while working at a beach restaurant as a young man (shown below).

Comment: So it's basically like Downfall parodies?

Comment: Think of those Downfall parodies (the movie is a documentary depicting Hitler's last ten days) with the scene where Hitler is yelling at his officers. To me the best executed one is the AP Physics C exam one in which Hitler rhetorically asks how the hell anyone can find the speed of a car using the alphabet, referring to how some problems on the AP Physics C exam have algebraic expressions for answers and not (yet) numbers.

Comment: from the video description: `Original Source: Risitas y las paelleras: https://youtu.be/cDphUib5iG4`